# Multipage and multiline JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to make a `JTable` that can be shown in multiple page(if rows exceed the maximum rows), and it also has a column(or cell) that can wrap multiline text. The problem is when it is set for multipage, its table model has already used for `AbstractTableModel`, and it can not be set(again) by `DefaultTableModel` which is needed in wrapping multiline text. I can run multipage table or multiline text column table separately, but when I combine both, the problem will arise. I have already search anywhere on internet, but no answer for my problem. Could anybody help me ?

This is the code of  `AbstractTableModel` I use for multipage table :

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private String[] columnNames = {"No.","Kode","Produk","Jasa","satuan", "harga", "qty", "jml"};
    private Vector data = new Vector();
    public final Object[] longValues = {"", "", "", false, "", new Double(20), new Integer(20), new Double(20)};

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return ((Vector) data.get(row)).get(col);
    }           

    public String getColumnName(int col){
        return columnNames[col];
    }
    public void setEmpty(int rows) {    
        int i = rows-1;
        while (i > -1) {
            data.removeElementAt(i); 
            i--;
        }

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public Class getColumnClass(int col){
        switch (col) {
            case 0:
                return String.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            case 2:
                return String.class;
            case 3:
                return Boolean.class;   
            case 4:
                return String.class; 
            case 5:
                return Double.class; 
            case 6:
                return Integer.class; 
            case 7:
                return Double.class; 
            default:
                return String.class;
        }
    }        
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
        ((Vector) data.get(row)).setElementAt(value, col);
        fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){            
        return true;            
    }
    public void insertData(Object[] values){
        data.add(new Vector());
        for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
            ((Vector) data.get(data.size()-1)).add(values[i]);
        }
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public void removeRow(int row){
        data.removeElementAt(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }
}
```

which I called it from `setGrid()` method :

```
public void setGrid() {
...
tabelItem = new Zebra();
btnRight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                nomorHalaman++;
                initPagination();
            }
 });
 panelNavigasi.add(btnRight);
...
}
```

The `initPagination()` use MyTableModel above to load records from table in MySQL database which can be set for how many rows in one page every time the user click navigation buttons(first, left, right, last) :

```
private void initPagination(){
    totalData=getItemRecNum();         
    jumlahBarisPerhalaman=Integer.valueOf(txtPagesize.getText());
    Double totalHalamanD=Math.ceil((double)totalData/(double)jumlahBarisPerhalaman);
    totalHalaman=totalHalamanD.intValue();        
    String HEADER[]={"No.","Kode","Produk","Jasa","satuan", "harga", "qty", "jml"};
    if(nomorHalaman.equals(1)){
        btnOne.setEnabled(false);
        btnLeft.setEnabled(false);
    }   else {
        btnOne.setEnabled(true);
        btnLeft.setEnabled(true);
    }

    if(nomorHalaman.equals(totalHalaman)){
        btnEnd.setEnabled(false);
        btnRight.setEnabled(false);
    }   else    {
        btnEnd.setEnabled(true);
        btnRight.setEnabled(true);
    }    
    if(nomorHalaman>totalHalaman){
        nomorHalaman=1;
    }        

    model = new MyTableModel();
  // Get records from MySQL DB according to page(offset) and rows per page      
    show(nomorHalaman, jumlahBarisPerhalaman);
    tabelItem.setModel(model);   

    lblPage.setText("p." + nomorHalaman + "/" + totalHalaman + "     ");
}
```

`Zebra` is a `class` that make zebra stripe table and I use it for multiline cell table :

```
public class Zebra extends JTable {
@Override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col) {
    Component cell = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    cell.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    if (row % 2 == 0) {
        cell.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);            
    } else {
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);            
    }
    return cell;
}
@Override public void doLayout() {
    TableColumn col = getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    for(int row=0; row<getRowCount(); row++) {
      Component c = prepareRenderer(col.getCellRenderer(), row, 2);
      if(c instanceof JTextArea) {
        JTextArea a = (JTextArea)c;
        int h = getPreferredHeight(a) + getIntercellSpacing().height;
        if(getRowHeight(row)!=h) setRowHeight(row, h);
      }
    }
    super.doLayout();
  }

  private int getPreferredHeight(JTextComponent c) {
    Insets insets = c.getInsets();
    View view = c.getUI().getRootView(c).getView(0);
    int preferredHeight = (int)view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    return preferredHeight + insets.top + insets.bottom;
  }

  class TextAreaCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    private final Color evenColor = new Color(230, 240, 255);
    public TextAreaCellRenderer() {
      super();
      setLineWrap(true);
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));
    }
    @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
      JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      if(isSelected) {
        setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
        setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
      } else {
        setForeground(table.getForeground());
        setBackground(table.getBackground());
        setBackground((row%2==0)?evenColor:getBackground());
      }
      setFont(table.getFont());
      setText((value ==null) ? "" : value.toString());
      return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd "suggest" the multiline line support should come from the Renderer, which should have nothing to do with the model.  That and/or you might need to use one or more proxy models which "filter" a preexisting model to meet your new needs

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but I got error : "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2 >= 0". It's because I call renderer for column 2(which is not initialized by the DeafultTableModel yet) :

Comment: This is the call for table : tabelItem.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaCellRenderer());... and I don't have any idea about proxy  models... I'm sorry.

Comment: What is a "page" in GUI terms? You usually put your `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`.

Answer (score 0):

I has already found solution of my problem. Maybe there are other ways, but this is enough for me right now. I made few modifications from the old source and I limit it for three rows, because the item names are not so long that need more than three lines. Aaron Digulla is right, it should come from the Renderer, that nothing to do with the model....thanks for your suggestion.

```
private int getPreferredHeight(JTextComponent c) {
    Insets insets = c.getInsets();
    View view = c.getUI().getRootView(c).getView(2);
    int preferredHeight = (int)view.getPreferredSpan(View.Y_AXIS);
    return preferredHeight + insets.top + insets.bottom;
} 
private void setMultiLine(JTable table, TableColumn col, int row) {    
    int tableRowHeight = table.getRowHeight();
    col.setCellRenderer(new TextAreaCellRenderer());
    Component c = table.prepareRenderer(col.getCellRenderer(), row, 2);
    if(c instanceof JTextArea) {
          JTextArea a = (JTextArea) c;
          int h = getPreferredHeight(a) +     table.getIntercellSpacing().height;               
          if(h > tableRowHeight) {
              if (tableRowHeight * 3 < h) 
                  table.setRowHeight(row, tableRowHeight * 3);
              else
                  table.setRowHeight(row, h);
          }
    }       
}
```